# MS-SQL Query - Update record retrieved via Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

***UPDATE ***

The scope has now developed slightly, and I now need to retreive the fields 'Id, uri, linkTo'. How does this change things???

I'm using an MS-SQL 2005 db and have the following stored procedure;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getNewAds
(
@region
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 Id, uri, linkTo FROM Adverts
ORDER BY NEWID()
WHERE adRegion = @region
END
```

I would like to then add '1' to the column named adShown in the same table, for the single result retrieved. What is the simplest / quickest means to do this within the same procedure?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a quirky update syntax that will let you assign the value to a variable at the same time as performing an update, but I'm not going to show it to you because it is undocumented, unsupported, and I can't guarantee that it will continue to work in future versions of SQL Server. Here is the method I would recommend (assuming Id is PK or at least unique):

```
DECLARE 
  @Id INT, 
  @uri VARCHAR(2048),
  @linkTo VARCHAR(2048);

SELECT TOP 1 @Id = Id, @uri = uri, @linkTo = linkTo
  FROM dbo.Adverts
  WHERE adRegion = @region
  ORDER BY NEWID();

UPDATE dbo.Adverts
  SET adShown = adShown + 1
  WHERE Id = @Id;

SELECT Id = @Id, uri = @uri, linkTo = @linkTo;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've been given a bit more info and now need to also retreive the columns 'id, uri, linkTo'. I tried adding these after @ID=id but get the error; A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Comment: Updated to reflect changed requirements.

Comment: A bit late, but I really should say thanks for the extra edit / update.

Answer (score 7):

try a single command:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getNewAds
(
@region  --lazy, declare type!!
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP (1) Adverts
        SET adShown = adShown + 1
        OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
        WHERE adRegion = @region
END
```

[UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) says that:

> TOP ( expression) [ PERCENT ]
>
> Specifies the number or percent of rows that will be updated.
>   expression can be either a number or a percent of the rows.
>
> The rows referenced in the TOP expression that is used with INSERT,
>   UPDATE, MERGE, or DELETE **are not arranged in any order.**

but in my limited testing (not many rows in the test table), it looks like it updates the same row each time, and that the OP is trying to update a different row each time.

so try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getNewAds
(
@region  --lazy, declare type!!
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID int

    --select row to update
    SELECT TOP 1 
        @ID=Id 
        FROM Adverts
        WHERE adRegion = @region
        ORDER BY NEWID()


    --update and return result set in one command
    UPDATE TOP (1) Adverts
        SET adShown = adShown + 1
        OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
        WHERE ID=@ID
END
```

Comment: @KM Thanks for the response. I've been given a bit more info and now need to also retreive the columns 'id, uri, linkTo'. I tried adding these after @ID=id but get the error; A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Comment: @Phill Healey, just select the @ID column as it is already doing.  however, in the UPDATE's OUTPUT clause include the columns you want: `INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.Uri, INSERTED.LinkTO` and your result set will include those columns.