# Read and Increment int value in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I need to read and increment a value atomically in SQL Server 2008, using c#.

For example, I have to insert items of a "lot", for this i need the number of the last lot and be sure, that no one else get this number.

So i have a table only with the last lot number, and find a way to get and update the number in only one step.

How can i do this?

Comment: Is it essential that the lot numbers be sequential? Why not just use an `identity`?

Comment: Maybe the quirky update methodology here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184410/sql-server-update-mytable-set-col1-value-col2-col1 or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653962/ms-sql-query-update-record-retrieved-via-stored-procedure could help.

Answer (score 2):

Is it essential that the lot numbers be sequential? Why not just use an `identity`? This is better in terms of concurrency as otherwise you need to block concurrent insert attempts in case they get rolled back and would leave a gap in the sequence.

If it absolutely is a requirement however you can do

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Sequence 
  (
     OneRow CHAR(1) DEFAULT('X') PRIMARY KEY CHECK(OneRow = 'X'),
     val    INT
  )
```

Insert a row with an initial seed.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Sequence 
            (val)
VALUES     (1)
```

Then to allocate a range of sufficient size for your insert (call it in the same transaction obviously)

```
CREATE PROC dbo.GetSequence
@val AS int OUTPUT,
@n as int =1
AS
UPDATE dbo.Sequence 
SET @val = val = (val + @n);
```

Comment: Just please be cautious of this "quirky update" syntax. My comment in the first linked question above leads to more info...

Comment: Documented where? And to last through to what version? I'm not saying it's a bad solution, it just doesn't pass my future-proofing test.

Comment: @Aaron `@variable = column = expression` is specifically allowed in the [`UPDATE Grammar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) and in the comments it says *SET @variable = column = expression sets the variable to the same value as the column. This differs from SET @variable = column, column = expression, which sets the variable to the pre-update value of the column.*

Comment: I wonder if that comment has been added in recent years. While I admit I haven't reviewed the docs in ages, I know this was something to stay away from for a long time. And it is important to note that issues can still occur if you're trying to do this for multiple rows...

Comment: @Aaron - Yep agreed that the use for running totals has lots of issues. I've added a check constraint to the table definition to ensure it can't contain more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just alter the table so that the lot number is an `identity` field and will auto-increment itself. Then you don't have to worry about incrementing in code.